# How to open an html file from inside a zip?

Tags: html, zip

Is there any way to open an html file from within a zip file which contains images the html references? I generate htmls with relative paths to resources and the browser won't find them in the zip file, I have to extract it first. Opening it from the zip would be ideal. Any way to do it?

Comment: Using what browser in what context?

Comment: Any browser. I simply wanted to double click on the html file inside the zip and have it open my default browser and find the images the html references that are sitting in the zip. As far as I know, that's impossible without first extracting the files.

Comment: I find this question very interesting. The Windows Explorer was implemented in a way that it is able to open zip files just like folders - so why not the browser? In our case, we get a new version of the documentation for some device every time a new firmware is created. And if you extract all, this gets very huge...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to extract it. When you double click on your html in the zip file, it is extracted in the background and shown to you, the only way to read anything in a compressed file is by extracting it.

Comment: Ah ok. I was hoping there was some way to create a path in my html which knows to look in the zip file.

Answer (score 5):

As I know, only Firefox can do this via
`jar:file://c:/myfolder/myzip.zip!/index.html`

Comment: Sadly, `jar:file:` only seem to work for local files. Neither `jar:http...` nor `jar:file:http...` are possible for internet files despite of being an [official IANA URI schema](https://www.iana.org/assignments/uri-schemes/prov/jar) (likely based on [JarURLConnection](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/net/JarURLConnection.html)).

Comment: As a side note, Artifactory allows that via [ArchiveEntryDownload REST API](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-ArchiveEntryDownload) (as pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47553439/522578)).

Comment: I use this to read zipped documentations.

Answer (score 0):

Your aim is to keep all those thousands htm, gif... files in one container? Considere using ISO file, it won't be compressed but nowedays HDD are big enough... Add an autorun.inf at the root if you like windows opening your CD/DVD. CDburnerXP is a freeware that can do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Falkon must enable the plugin for KDE-integration, that allows browsing a kio-slave with URLs like:

   ```
   zip:/home/user/path/to/archive.zip
   info:ls
   fish://benutzername@rechnername
   ...
   ```

   - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falkon
   - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KIO
2. At least Firefox can do the trick for documentation and configuration pages that are packaged inside an addon-xpi-file which is also basically a zip-archive. But I don't know any way of providing an arbitrary zip in the location-bar.
3. Eclipse can also point it's integrated browser to zipped java-doc.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is. if You look at the file name even a zip is notified as HTML.
So even 7 zip will try to add it to zip since it's a HTML. Browsers can't open the file neither. so the file extension is the culprit. It happens when You download a file from Linux and copy thet on an NTFS volume. A work around is to connect a NTFS volume to Linux check how it is stored there . and then connect this NTFS volume to windows but do not use fat32 or exfat cause it's no NTFS.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).