# Show content of a zip file in a browser, rather than downloading it

Tags: apache, browser, nginx, http-headers, zip

I have a log server, where users upload archives and view their content online when needed. Currently the server unzips files, right after receiving them. Unfortunately, my peers consumed all the drive space I had. I can free up a lot of space, if there's a way of storing ZIP archives, but feeding them to users as HTML page (same as default Apache's file browser).

I know there are solutions relying on JS, like:

- http://gildas-lormeau.github.io/zip.js/demos/demo2.html
- https://stuk.github.io/jszip/

or I can unzip them on demand at server side and provide link to a temporary folder. However, some time ago I've heard a browser can view an archive content if proper headers are sent from Apache/nginx. Apache's mod-deflate doesn't help much here and I can't find other docs - perhaps it's not possible after all?

Cheers.

Comment: May be some browser have that feature, but in general browsers don't work with archives. But zip files have directory part, so there is no need to unpack whole archive just to send zip file listing, and probably there is apache module for that.

Comment: I'm aware it's not a standard web browser feature, but was hoping that Chrome or Firefox provide it by default; thanks for the tip with file listing - will take a closer look at it tomorrow

Comment: Did you found any solution on this ? I know its been 5 years since you posted but still ? :)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11657446/how-to-open-an-html-file-from-inside-a-zip

Comment: Related: [Download single file from zipped Artifactory artifact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47536315/download-single-file-from-zipped-artifactory-artifact)